# Return keys and values from multiple object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

could anyone help me with this issue:

how to return keys and values from multiple object in array. Simple example:

```
let arr = [{ 1: 'a' }, { 2: 'b' }, { 3: 'c' }, { 4: 'd' }];
```

I need to check if in this arr is specific key and value. arr.map(el => el)) return whole array.

I think I'm braind dead and cannot figure it out...

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: adding real case:

```
"dates": [
 {
  "6.01.2020": []
 },
 {
  "7.01.2020": []
 },
 {
  "8.01.2020": []
 },
 {
  "9.01.2020": []
 }
],
```

Comment: Please tell some input and expected output?

Comment: btw, why do you have different keys?

Comment: So `check(2, 'b', arr)` would return `true` and `check(2, 'x', arr)` would return false?

Comment: Ola, it sounds like you're saying you want to filter an array of objects (not map), so I've marked a question whose answers show you how to do that. If that's not what you want to do, please clarify the question and we can reopen it (or point you at a different existing one that will help).

Comment: If my interpretation was correct, and T.J Crowder's duplicate does not do what you want, something like this might help: `const check = (key, val, arr) => arr.some (obj => obj[key] === val)`.  Then `check(2, 'b', arr)` would be `true` and `check(2, 'x', arr)` would be `false`.

Comment: T.J Crowder's sorry, but this case is a little bit different - I have different keys (over there are same keys with different values)

Comment: I've added an arr that I have a problem with. It's from JSON server